# ASP.NET text box lines disappear

Tags: asp.net, textbox

when i try to dynamicly change the text of a textbox,
if there is a line break, \r\n , all the text after the line break disappears including the line break sign.
only single lines are updated correctly.
the textbox is set to MultiLine TextMode.

what could cause such behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `vbCrLf` for new lines.

Example :

```
TextBox1.Text = "First Line " & vbCrLf & "Second Line"
```